# in-place backreferencing with sed

Tags: linux, sed, backreference, in-place

Can anyone help explain why

```
sed -re 's/(e)\1{2,}/ee/g' filename
```

Outputs (as desired)

```
Jeep
```

But

```
sed -ire 's/(e)\1{2,}/ee/g' filename
```

Gives me

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: Invalid back reference
```

I've tried fiddling around and putting escape brackets in different places but I'm not sure what else to do now.

Comment: That's very curious. I see a similar error in FreeBSD, which is using a different sed entirely.  My guess is that sed's case insensitivity is not implemented by assuming that every letter is a set of both cases of that letter, and that the backreference just doesn't know what to look for. You'll see that `sed -re 's/([Ee])\1{2,}/ee/g'` works just fine. Perhaps you can refactor your sed script manually.

Comment: Can you give more background on the overall problem you're trying to solve, or is this question purely academic?

Comment: Your example can be reduced to just `'s/eee*/ee/g'`

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate but cannot find a good target to mark it as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `-ire` specifies `re` as the argument to `-i`, not as options to `sed`.

Specifying `-i` as a separate individual option works fine.

```
sed -i -re 's/(e)\1{2,}/ee/g' file
```